# Is it possible to mock a method chained through an attribute?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have the following PHP function, for which I am trying to write a PHPUnit test:

```
public function getDisplayMode()
{
    if($this->request->query->get('master_video'))
    {
        return 'listTranslations';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'default';
    }
}
```

The line `$this->request->query->get('master_video')` is what I am having trouble with.

I have mocked up the `request` object, so if it were just `$this->request->get('master_video')`, I could easily use the `method` method to tell my system what should be returned by `get`.

But I don't know how to do that when the `query` property is assumed to be present. (I don't know of any `property` method on my mock object, for example.)

Is there a way to define what should be returned by the `get` method here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mock of `query` and specify what happens on `->get()`.  The test would end up looking something like this:

```
public function testGetDisplayMode() {
    $mockQuery = $this->getMockBuilder('Query') // Or whatever the query class is
         ->setMethods(['get'])
         ->getMock();

    $mockQuery->expects($this->once())
         ->method('get')
         ->with('master_video')
         ->willReturn('foo');

    $mockRequest = $this->getMockBuilder('Request') // Or whatever the request is
         ->getMock();

    $mockRequest->query = $mockQuery;

    $sut = new Bar($mockRequest) // Or however you instantiate the class with the mock request.

    $mode = $sut->getDisplayMode();
    // Do your assertions on the returned mode here.
}
```

As a general rule, I have found when I am doing things like this where I have a mock object returning a mock object that it is a code smell.  Your method here doesn't need the $this->request it needs the query object.  You should be giving this directly to the object or passing it into this method.

Without knowing more about the class that you are making, I can't give more advice.

If something is hard to write a test for, it is a sign that you have not optimally designed your code.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. (I also agree about the code smell. This is a situation where I'm writing tests for a class that I'm not able to modify.)